# A better or more efficient version of this SQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on learning SQL queries, but I haven't really figured out what's more efficient.

This is my code:

```
SELECT A.CustName, A.CustID, C.RestName, 
CONCAT(A.Address, ' - ', C.Address, ' + ', C.FoodTime, ' = ', A.Address - C.Address + C.FoodTime) 
AS DeliveryTime, B.OrderID
FROM (SELECT * FROM Customers) AS A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Orders) AS B
ON A.CustID = B.CustID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Restaurants) AS C
ON B.RestID = C.RestID
ORDER BY A.CustID;
```

There are three tables, `Customers`, `Restaurants`, and `Orders`. Customers contains CustID, CustName and Address. Restaurants contains RestID, RestName, Address and FoodTime. Orders contains CustID, RestID and OrderID.

I believe this is an exercise in dimensions and facts, but I'm not 100% about the proper way for these to interact in terms of tables. If anyone has a good explanation for that, I'm all ears (eyes). Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with that `CONCAT`? What type is the `Address` column?

Comment: CONCAT is just to show in the table what is going on in that column. Those cells could simply be:
 
    A.Address - C.Address + C.FoodTime

for the purpose of this question.

Comment: What's the thinking behind using, e.g.  `(SELECT * FROM Customers) AS B` rather than just `Customers AS B`?

Comment: Originally I had it pulling specific columns from those tables. If other columns in the tables were _very_ large, would it make sense to use (SELECT CustID, Address FROM Customers) from a memory/efficiency standpoint?

Comment: @SteveK No. The query engine/optimiser will work out from your overall query which columns are actually needed, and automatically only fetch those. You don't need to spoon-feed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually need information on all the customers for all orders in all restaurants, then your query will "work". As already pointed out (select * from sometable) and (sometable), with or without brackets, are the same thing, and most people would just put the table name.

The first part of the concat will show you the address and foodtime info. The second part where you try to subtract an address from another address and then add a time, is probably going to get you an error, depending on the database used (if your database interprets "+" as a concatenation operator, and the addresses can actually be subtracted, then you *might* get a valid string, but it seems unlikely).

Thirdly, as a matter of style, giving aliases a,b and c to your tables is just likely to confuse you. One character aliases are OK, but in this case whey wouldn't you use r for restaurant, o for orders and c for customers?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. This is exactly what I was looking for, comments on "good practice" and such.

Answer (score 0):

First, avoid the useless `(SELECT * FROM xxx) AS zzz` this should work better :

```
SELECT C.CustName, C.CustID, R.RestName, 
    CONCAT(C.Address, ' - ', R.Address, ' + ', R.FoodTime, ' = ', C.Address - R.Address + R.FoodTime) 
    AS DeliveryTime, O.OrderID
FROM Customers AS C
LEFT JOIN Orders AS O
    ON C.CustID = O.CustID
LEFT JOIN Restaurants AS R
    ON O.RestID = R.RestID
ORDER BY C.CustID;
```

Next, what are you really trying to do ?

Comment: It's just an exercise, so what I'm trying to do is just display what I have in the initial select statement in a "current order" table. Thank you for writing it out in a preferable format. This helps a lot.